# Alsaequal volume gain, Pre-Amp like

Tags: audio, alsa

I use alsaequal for equalize my audio, hitherto ok, but all know that after equalizer the volume is low, some equalizers have a control called "Pre-AMP" that solve this problem, but in Alsaequal haven't this control.

I've tried using ALSA's softvol plugin but this plugin cause distortion, that isn't acceptable for me!

So, someone have a solution for me ?

Comment: Does the solution have to use alsaequal or is something else OK?

Comment: @slm no, solution can use something else.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to alsaequal that I've used in the past is called [`normalize`](http://normalize.nongnu.org/).

> Normalize is a tool for adjusting the volume of audio files to a
>   standard level. This is useful for things like creating mixed CD's and
>   mp3 collections, where different recording levels on different albums
>   can cause the volume to vary greatly from song to song.

#### Examples

```
$ normalize -a -10dBFS -b *.mp3
```

#### References

- [Linux audio tools: Is there a way to normalize the volume of .ogg files?](https://superuser.com/questions/23156/linux-audio-tools-is-there-a-way-to-normalize-the-volume-of-ogg-files)

Comment: normalize adjust the sound volume, alsaequal is an equalizer, it's two things different!

Comment: @VictorAurélio - OK, I'm not familiar with that app. Sorry, I'll keep digging.

Comment: @VictorAurélio - is anything on this page helpful? http://wanners.net:8000/blog/2011/09/alsa-realtime-sound-pipeline/

Comment: after I'll look on this